# In following code why JVM is giving more time to a particular thread compared to the other?

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

When i run the both the code  , the Thread containing the runnable code gets into action only when i press send button in GUI .But i read that JVM chooses thread randomly and gives times to each thread ,  but here it seems JVM is giving more time to GUI to run and Thread containing runnable gets time only when i press send button.

Client code -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
```

`public class SimpleChatClient
{`

```
JTextArea incoming;
JTextField outgoing;
BufferedReader reader;
PrintWriter writer;
Socket sock;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SimpleChatClient client = new SimpleChatClient();
    client.go();
}


public void go()
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Ludicrously Simple Chat Client");
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    incoming  = new JTextArea(15,30);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    outgoing = new JTextField(20);
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
    sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
    mainPanel.add(qScroller);
    mainPanel.add(outgoing);
    mainPanel.add(sendButton);
    setUpNetworking();

    Thread readThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
    readThread.start();

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER , mainPanel);
    frame.setSize(400,500);
    frame.setVisible(true);


}

private void setUpNetworking()
{
    try{
        String ip;
        ip = "localhost";
        sock = new Socket(ip,5000);
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("networking established");
    }catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    {
        try{
            writer.println(outgoing.getText());
            writer.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        outgoing.setText("");
        outgoing.requestFocus();



    }
}

public class IncomingReader implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {   int i = 0;

        String message;
        try{

            while((message = reader.readLine())!=null) 
            {
```

`/*THIS THREAD RUNS ONLY WHEN I PRESS SEND BUTTON IN GUI */`

```
                System.out.println("YES YES I am HERE");
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
                System.out.println("There");
                ++i;
                System.out.println(i);
            }

        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

}
```

`}`

Server code -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
```

`public class VerySimpleChatServer`
{

```
ArrayList clientOutputStreams;

public class ClientHandler implements Runnable
{
    BufferedReader reader;
    Socket sock;

    public ClientHandler(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        try{
            sock = clientSocket;
            InputStreamReader isReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(isReader);
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    }

    public void run()
    {
        String message;

        try{
            while((message = reader.readLine())!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("read  " + message);
                tellEveryone(message);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){ex.printStackTrace();}

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new VerySimpleChatServer().go();
}

public void go()
{
    clientOutputStreams  =  new ArrayList();

    try{
        ServerSocket serverSock = new ServerSocket(5000);

        while(true)
        {
            Socket clientSocket  = serverSock.accept();
            PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientOutputStreams.add(writer);


            Thread t = new Thread(new ClientHandler(clientSocket));
            t.start();
            System.out.println("got a connection");

        }

    }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void tellEveryone(String message)
{
    Iterator it  = clientOutputStreams.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        try{
            PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) it.next();
            writer.println(message);
            writer.flush();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`}`

Comment: I gave 4 hours and tried different method to understand it but i was unsuccessful .

Comment: The thread is running, it's just blocked on I/O waiting for something to read.

Comment: @NathanHughes But in that case it should read null and loop should exit

Comment: @NathanHughes Can you prove or justify your point ?

Comment: @everyone can you at least upvote the question if you cannot answer it ?

Comment: no, when it returns null that means it found EOF, blocked means it waits for something to read. that's why it's called blocking I/O.

Comment: @NathanHughes i have used i/o as buffered oriented which is non blocking.

Comment: @NathanHughes please refer to https://www.javatpoint.com/java-nio-vs-input-output

Comment: @NathanHughes  If you make simple java I/O program having only main thread the reader will not wait.

Comment: @NathanHughes Thanks man . I got the point